Iot.Device.Imu.Mpu6050 - System.IO.IOException
I am struggling to calibrate an Mpu 6050 specifcially it is a;
Adafruit MPU-6050 6-DoF Accel and Gyro Sensor - STEMMA QT Qwiic
which is connected to a Raspberry Pi 2.
When I try to call the .CalibrateGyroscopeAccelerometer(); method I get the error;
System.IO.IOException: Can set GyroscopeBandwidth, desired value Bandwidth0184Hz, stored value Bandwidth0250Hz
 public HardwareAccelerometerController(
     ILogger<HardwareAccelerometerController> logger,
     int i2cAddress,
     int recalibrationIntervalMinutes,
     int i2cBusId = 1)
 {
     _logger = logger;

     try
     {
         var i2cSettings = new I2cConnectionSettings(i2cBusId, i2cAddress);
         var i2cDevice = I2cDevice.Create(i2cSettings);

         _mpu6050 = new Mpu6050(i2cDevice);  // Initialize the MPU6050
         _logger.LogInformation($"MPU6050 initialized with I2C address {i2cAddress} on bus {i2cBusId}.");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         _logger.LogError(ex, $"Failed to initialize MPU6050 with I2C address {i2cAddress} on bus {i2cBusId}. Check connections and configuration.");
         throw new InvalidOperationException("MPU6050 initialization failed. Ensure the device is connected and configured correctly.", ex);
     }

     _recalibrationIntervalMinutes = recalibrationIntervalMinutes;
     _lastCalibrationTime = DateTime.Now;
 }

 /// <summary>
 /// Calibrate the accelerometer and gyroscope.
 /// </summary>
 public async Task CalibrateAsync()
 {
 if (_mpu6050 == null)
 {
     _logger.LogError("Cannot calibrate MPU6050 because it is not initialized.");
     throw new InvalidOperationException("MPU6050 is not initialized.");
 }

 await Task.Run(() =>
 {
     _logger.LogInformation("Calibrating MPU6050...");
     try
     {
         _mpu6050.CalibrateGyroscopeAccelerometer();
         _logger.LogInformation("Calibration complete.");
     }
     catch (IOException ex)
     {
         _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to set the GyroscopeBandwidth. Proceeding with default bandwidth.");
     }
 });

}
From the logger the device is initilised;
MPU6050 initialized with I2C address 104 on bus 1.
From running sudo i2cdetect -y 1 on the pi I get
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

So the unit is present - i have also tried the a python sript which is returning data from the unit.
I cannot find any detail on this specific error? Can anyone tell me how to debug this and what I may be doing wrong please?
Update
I have tried setting the bandwidth specifically on the Mpu6050 class, this appears to change the value but still the error continues?
_logger.LogInformation($"Gyroscope bandwidth is set to {_mpu6050.GyroscopeBandwidth}");
_logger.LogInformation($"Attempting to set the gyroscope bandwidth to Bandwidth0184Hz.");
_mpu6050.GyroscopeBandwidth = GyroscopeBandwidth.Bandwidth0184Hz;
_logger.LogInformation($"Gyroscope bandwidth now set to {_mpu6050.GyroscopeBandwidth}");

_mpu6050.CalibrateGyroscopeAccelerometer();

does output that the value has changed.

Your bug report https://github.com/dotnet/iot/issues/2356 is on the correct place.
